# How to test if a plot was plotted in R?

Tags: r, unit-testing, plot, ggplot2, plotly

Is it possible to create a unit test in *R* (e.g., using `testthat` package), which tests each of the following:

1. if R `base` plot was created;
2. if `lattice`/`trellis`object was printed;
3. if `ggplot2`object was printed;
4. if `plotly` object was printed?

Comment: Base plot returns (invisibly) `NULL`, so you could perhaps use that to create a test.  Don't know about the others.

Comment: Can check for the existence of a plot of the correct name in the default directory?